# How to open FileDialogue with sharepoint website folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, vba

I want to open and browse my SharePoint folder and select a file from there like we select file from local file. But I see only the file dialogue with empty like below.

[image: Empty File Dialogue]

**My function below:**

```
Function GetOpenFilenameSharePoint() As Variant
Dim SharePointPath As String
SharePointPath = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/teams/folder1/folder2/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Ffolder0%2Ffolder1%2Ffolder2%2Ffolder4%2Ffolder5%5F8&FolderCTID=0x012000EEE5487829FC134FB89F51D5F5A4CCC1"
With Application.FileDialog(3)
  .InitialFileName = SharePointPath
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls"
  .Title = Title
  If .Show Then
    GetOpenFilenameSharePoint = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
  Else
    GetOpenFilenameSharePoint = False
  End If
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code to open a file from a SharePoint site:

```
Dim SummaryWB As Workbook
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .InitialFileName = "https://sharepoint.com/team/folder" & "\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
        Set SummaryWB = Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem)
    Next
End With

If SummaryWB Is Nothing then Exit Sub
```

Similar issue for reference: [Open an Excel file from SharePoint site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505513/open-an-excel-file-from-sharepoint-site)

*Note: Microsoft is providing this information as a convenience to you. The sites are not controlled by Microsoft. Microsoft cannot make any representations regarding the quality, safety, or suitability of any software or information found there. Please make sure that you completely understand the risk before retrieving any suggestions from the above link.*